# Three.js: Load JSON file to be viewed in

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, webgl, blender

i have a question regarding putting a 3dModel from Blender to a Three.js page.
I have created a 3D Human model in blender. I can export it using the 2.66 three.js-export plugin for blender.

When I use the exported .js file and load it into http://blackjk3.github.io/threefab/ it seems to work fine.

I used the http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_animation_skinning_morph.html example and tried to put my own model into it. And I can't get it to be displayed.

Firebug just tells me something like: "TypeError: a.hierarchy is undefined" and it seems like I can't really find the problem.

I use the JSON Loader as ususal:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "models/skinned/humanPrototype.js", function ( geometry, materials ) { createScene( geometry, materials, 0, FLOOR, -300, 60 ) } );
```

createScene looks like this:

```
function createScene( geometry, materials, x, y, z, s ) {
            geometry.computeBoundingBox();
            var bb = geometry.boundingBox;

            THREE.AnimationHandler.add( geometry.animation );


            for ( var i = 0; i < materials.length; i ++ ) {
                var m = materials[ i ];
                m.skinning = true;
                m.morphTargets = true;

                m.color.setHSL( 0.6, 0.5, 0.6 );
                m.ambient.copy( m.color );

                m.wrapAround = true;
            }

            mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
            mesh.position.set( 0,0,0 );
            mesh.scale.set( s, s, s );
            scene.add( mesh );

            mesh.castShadow = true;
            mesh.receiveShadow = true;

            animation = new THREE.Animation( mesh, geometry.animation.name );
            animation.JITCompile = false;
            animation.interpolationType = THREE.AnimationHandler.LINEAR;

            //animation.play();

        }
```

Since my model is loadable in threefab I think its ok. I guess I need to change something about the code. I feel this to be a inexact question and I want to apologize for that. But at the moment I'm really stuck. Any suggestions? =) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Open knight.js and your exported.js file with an text editor, you will find the difference,
I think that this is still an experiment technology by the author.